# MS Graph beta/applications OData property 'resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions' does not exist on type 'microsoft.graph.apiApplication'

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, powerquery

I'm writing some power query against the Graph API and when I try to pull OData from the applications resource I get the error:

> DataSource.Error: OData: The property 'resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions' does not exist on type 'microsoft.graph.apiApplication'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.
>   Details:
>       DataSourceKind=OData
>       DataSourcePath=https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications

`Source = OData.Feed(AppsURL,[#"Content-Type"="application/json", Authorization = AccessTokenHeader])`

If I do the same but as a REST API request I get the JSON but then I need to take care of paging and transformation.

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(AppsURL, 
    [
        Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json", 
        Authorization = AccessTokenHeader
        ]
    ]))
```

If I do the same against https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals the OData.Feed method works like a charm.
Any possible work around or do I need to wait for the API to be fixed before consuming that resource?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some tracing I found the schema is verified at: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata and it is missing one definition.

To original response:

```
<ComplexType Name="apiApplication">
<Property Name="acceptMappedClaims" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
<Property Name="knownClientApplications" Type="Collection(Edm.Guid)"/>
<Property Name="preAuthorizedApplications" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.preAuthorizedApplication)"/>
<Property Name="requestedAccessTokenVersion" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
<Property Name="oauth2PermissionScopes" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.permissionScope)" Nullable="false" />
</ComplexType>
```

Is missing:

```
<Property Name="resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.resourceSpecificPermission)" Nullable="false"/>
```

As a workaround I added a rule to Fidller:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("graph.microsoft.com") && oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","application/xml;charset=utf-8") && oSession.PathAndQuery == '/beta/$metadata' ){
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
    oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('<Property Name="oauth2PermissionScopes" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.permissionScope)" Nullable="false" />','<Property Name="oauth2PermissionScopes" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.permissionScope)" Nullable="false" /><Property Name="resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.resourceSpecificPermission)" Nullable="false"/>');
}
```